# Jupyter: how to search kernels only in one path

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I defined JUPYTER_PATH containing only a trusted set of kernels.
Is there an option to disable the search of kernels specs files in all other dirs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved running

```
jupyter notebook '--KernelSpecManager.whitelist=["ir"]'
```

Source of solution in this comment: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/issues/144#issuecomment-242148826